# Trying to save reference of closure, but not living long enough

Tags: rust

I'm rather new to rust, and I'm struggling with the lifetime stuff rn. So basically I'm constructing a struct and I want to store a closure in that struct. But one of the captured variables does not live long enough.

```
struct HtmlOut<'a> {
  echo_escaped: &'a dyn Fn(&String)
}

// not really implemented yet
fn escape(s: &String) -> &String {
  return s;
}

impl<'a> HtmlOut<'a> {
  
  fn new(echo: &'a dyn Fn(&String)) -> HtmlOut<'a> {
    let echo_element_escaped_cls = |s: &String| { echo(escape(s)) };
    let echo_element_escaped: &'a dyn Fn(&String) = &echo_element_escaped_cls;
    return HtmlOut {
      echo_escaped: echo_element_escaped
    }
  }
}
```

I get two errors:

```
|s: &String| { echo(escape(s)) };
------------   ^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
```

and

```
&'a dyn Fn(&String) = &echo_element_escaped_cls;
-------------------   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
|
type annotation requires that `echo_element_escaped_cls` is borrowed for `'a`
```

My questions are:

- why does echo not live long enough, when everything is annotated with the same lifetime specifier `'a`?
- how do I rewrite this code so that `echo` lives long enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can't work as written simply because references have to refer to *something*. Rust doesn't have a GC, so you can't just create a value in a function, create a reference to it, and return the reference from the function. You need to *own* the value instead, which you do either by storing the value inside the struct, or in the case of `dyn Trait` trait objects, by boxing it:

```
struct HtmlOut {
    echo_escaped: Box<dyn Fn(&str)>,
}
```

(I also modified the signature to accept `&str` rather than `&String` which is more flexible and works as nicely, details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/).)

The other problem is with your `escape` function - to escape a string, it has to be able to *create* the escaped string, not just return the reference to a string created by someone else. It needs to either accept `&mut String` to modify the string in-place, or return an owned `String`:

```
// not really implemented yet
fn escape(s: &str) -> String {
    s.to_string()
}
```

Finally, the constructor needs to accept `echo` as an owned value, so it can be moved into the closure:

```
impl HtmlOut {
    fn new(echo: Box<dyn Fn(&str)>) -> HtmlOut {
        let echo_element_escaped_cls = move |s: &str| echo(&escape(s));
        let echo_element_escaped = Box::new(echo_element_escaped_cls);
        return HtmlOut {
            echo_escaped: echo_element_escaped,
        };
    }
}
```

For maximum flexibility the constructor could even accept an arbitrary closure and do the boxing as its own implementation detail:

```
fn new<F: Fn(&str) + 'static>(echo: F) -> HtmlOut {
    let echo = Box::new(echo);
    let echo_element_escaped_cls = move |s: &str| echo(&escape(s));
    let echo_element_escaped = Box::new(echo_element_escaped_cls);
    return HtmlOut {
        echo_escaped: echo_element_escaped,
    };
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=06104414f8a6487799a29bf04fb8bf5a)